# On independent sets of graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Given $G$ a regular graph on $n$ vertices, denote $\alpha(G)>1$ to be independence number.

Denote $\Gamma(G)$ to be collection of possible subset of independent vertices in $G$ of cardinality $\alpha(G)-1$.

To each $\gamma\in\Gamma(G)$, assign number $N(\gamma)$ reflecting number of ways $\gamma$ could be extended by an additional vertex so that augmented subset remains independent (attains cardinality number $\alpha(G)$).

Denote $N(G)=\max_{\gamma\in\Gamma(G)}N(\gamma)$.

Denote $M(G)$ to be maximum number of disjoint independent sets of $G$ that attain cardinality $\alpha(G)$ (that is each subset in $M(G)$ should be disjoint with cardinality $\alpha(G)$).

Easy to observe that $M(G)\leq\frac{|V|}{\alpha(G)}$.

Given fixed real $r>3$ (example $3.00002$), is there a graph (family) such that $$M(G)>|V|^{\frac{r-1}{f(r)}}>|V|^{\frac{1}{f(r)}}> \max(N(G),\alpha(G))$$ where $|V|$ is vertex number with some function $f(r)\geq r$?

Comment: Your notion $\ f(\alpha(G)\ N(G))\ :=\ \max(\alpha(G)\ N(G)),\ $ and similar functions $\ f(\alpha(G)\ N(G))\ $ introduce an interesting internal pressure to the graphs, and it should lead to a whole subtopic.

Comment: Turbo, about def. of $\ M(G).\ $ Is $\ M(G)\ $ the maximal cardinality of a family of pairwise disjoint independent sets of cardinality $\ \alpha(G)\ $? -- so we would have $\ M(G)\ \le\ \binom n{\alpha(G)}\ $ (where $\ n\ $ is the number of vertices).

Comment: Thank you. But at least what I called my *small EXAMPLE* was fine, I was not confused at that stage.

Comment: So if $\max(\alpha(G),N(G))<|V|^{\frac{1}{cr}}$, then we could hope $|V|^{\frac{r-1}{cr}}<|V|^{\frac{cr-1}{cr}}\leq M(G)$ is possible. It seems that if $c\gg1$, an example of graph family is feasible.

Comment: I slightly and equivalently reformulated you definition of $\ M(G)\ $ ok. In my comment I got confused only about its conclusion. Of course, as you've written, $\ M(G)\le\frac n{\alpha(G)}$.

Comment: I think that **only** my accidental conclusion was wrong (a result of a mistaken *thinking* at that moment--my concentration gave up when I mixed the general definition and the peculiarities of my construction). Another equivalent formulation: $\ m:=M(G)\ $ is the largest integer such that there exists $\ W\subseteq V\ $ such that $\ |W|=\alpha(G)\cdot m\ $ and W is a union of $\ m\ $ maximal independent sets (i.e. od independent sets $\ J\subseteq V\ $ such that $\ |J|=\alpha(G)$).

Comment: Definition same as in query. We will get $M(G)\leq \frac{|V|}{\alpha(G)}\ll\binom{|V|}{\alpha(G)}$.

Comment: Yes, as an upper bound. These are trivially equivalent (sorry to inertially waste time on my talking).

Comment: $\alpha(G)\ $ and $\ N(G)\ $ have to be balanced to get an objectively good inequality, however possibly not as good as you'd like it--it has to be seen.

Answer (score 2):

Take $G = K_n$ the complete graph on $n$ vertices. Then $\alpha(G) = 1<N(G) = n$.

Comment: Consider $K_n$ with an additional isolated vertex. Or if you want a connected graph connect this vertex to some vertex of the complete graph.

Answer (score 2):

> **EXAMPLE** (small)

Let $\ A\ $ be a 5-element set. Let $\ V:=\binom A2.\ $ Let the set of edges be

$$E\ :=\ \left\{\left\{u\ v\right\}\in \binom V2\ :\ |u\cap v|=1\right\}$$

Then, for $\ G:=(V\ E),\ $ we have:

- $\ \alpha(G)=2$
- $\ N(G)=3$
- $\ M(G)=5$

Thus the answer to all three parts of question 1 is YES--there is a single requested example (it's a regular graph, with $\ \alpha(G)>1$).

> **General Construction**

Now let $\ |A|=3\cdot k-1\ $ for an arbitrary $\ k\ge 2.\ $ Let $\ V:=\binom A k\ $ and
$$E\ :=\ \left\{\left\{u\ v\right\}\in \binom V2\ :\ 1\le |u\cap v|<k \right\}$$

Then

- $\ \alpha(G)=2$
- $\ N(G)=\binom{2\cdot k-1}k$

> **PROOFS**

The independent sets in my example are pairwise disjont $k$-subsets of the $(3\cdot k-1)$-set A. Thus the maximal independent sets are exactly pairs of two disjoint $k$-sets, hence

$$\alpha(G)\ =\ 2$$

**REMARK 1**   Every(!) $\ (\alpha(G)-1)$-independent set is contained in the same maximal number $\ N(G)\ $ of the maximal independent sets.

**Next**, in the case of this (general) example, the independent $(\alpha(G)-1)$-sets are simply $1$-element sets, where the single element is an arbitrary $k$-set $\ X.\ $ You may extend such an independent set $\ \{A\}\ $ by selecting any $\ k$-subset $\ Y\subseteq A\setminus X.\ $ This shows that:

$$N(G)\ := \binom{2\cdot k-1}k$$

Comment: Could you tell me what does *oic* mean?

Comment: I think your count for $M(G)$ is off. $M(G)$ is a collection of subsets with each subset disjoint having cardinality exactly $\alpha(G)$.

Comment: I fixed $\ M(G)$--now it's perfect! (every k-subset is used). In particulat the small example got improved as the result.

Comment: This *general* (:-) example is done; it's time for a more dramatic one, hey!

Comment: So corollary $(N(G))^2 < M(G) < (N(G))^3\implies$ no example to $(2)$ exists?

Comment: No yet, but there should be more fun ahead of us :-)

Comment: I think if you use $|A|=dk-1$, you can get better.

Comment: Perhaps. This and variations were on my mind, but I wanted to finish first step to answer properly on your question. Just to establish the $\ \LaTeX\ $ phrases was hard to me (I am slow). Now wider possibilities are open.

Comment: The last portion of the general part was wrong (the two preceding portions, and the *small example*, were fine).

Answer (score -1):

It occurs to me that the complement is much easier to consider.

Then $M(G)$ is the number of disjoint maximum cliques, $\alpha (G)$ is the clique number and $N(G)$ is whatever.

If we start from a cubic graph, let's say $K_4$, and blow-up every vertex into a triangle at each step, then in the resulting graph the maximum size of a clique is always 3 and the only triangles are blowed-up vertices from the previous graph. So, let $G_n$ be the graph from $K_4$ by blowing up all vertices $n$ times. Then
$$ |V(G_n)| = 3^n \cdot 4$$
$$ M(G_n) = |V(G_{n-1})| = 3^{n-1} \cdot 4$$
And $N(G)$ is the maximum number of possible ways of extending a single edge into a triangle, which is 1 since the triangles in $G_n$ are disjoint.
So, by taking the complement

$$ M(G_n^c) = |V|/3 > |V|^{(r-1)/f(r)} > |V|^{1/f(r)} > \max \{N(G_n^c), \alpha(G_n^c)\} = \max \{ 1, 3\} = 3$$

I don't think the conditions on $r$ and $f(r)$ actually matters anyway, once you obtain linear number of $M(G)$ and bounded size of $N(G)$ and $\alpha(G)$. I started with dense regular graphs if it helps you. I hope my abuse of notations between complement and the original graph does not bother you.

Comment: something seems incorrect. Let me carefully check.

Comment: I know for a fact $M(G)$ cannot be arbitrarily big compared to $N(G),\alpha(G)$.

Comment: If you did not understand the construction then point out where you missed. The graph does not have a single pair of triangles sharing an edge.

Comment: Can you show some pictures?

Comment: Define blow up please.

Comment: [link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/116437/counting-spanning-trees-when-blowing-up-vertices) has nice figure which is the graph $G_1$ in my definition. Given a vertex $v$ with neighbors $x,y,z$, blowing-up $v$ is to remove $v$ then add three new vertices $v_x, v_y, v_z$ forming a triangle and also edges $v_x x$, $v_y y$, $v_z z$.

Comment: this is strange. may be i missed something.